# Pinterest OAuth 2 - Asp.net gives error

Tags: asp.net, oauth, pinterest

I have followed these steps to implement Pinterest OAuth : http://wiki.gic.mx/pinterest-developers/

when i send user to Authorize: https://pinterest.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=AppId
&redirect_uri=url.......
&scope=read

it's url is https://www.pinterest.com/oauth/?redirected=1 and shows me following screen:
[image]

what should i do now, i need Pinterest Oauth working ASAP.